# Gerrit trigger does not comments automaticly - error from jenkins: The url to submit to is not valid

Tags: jenkins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I am trying to figure out why Gerrit Trigger in Jenkins does not report back to Gerrit output from job (leave comment).

Job is triggered by gerrit,proper git change is used in build,job completes,no error in build console.

Using `ssh -p $GERRIT_PORT <gerrit_user>@$GERRIT_HOST gerrit review -m '"Comment"' --verified +1 $GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION` makes a comment though.

This is the only log from var/log/jenkins:

```
 Jun 09, 2017 11:27:05 AM com.sonymobile.tools.gerrit.gerritevents.workers.rest.AbstractRestCommandJob run
SEVERE: Gerrit response: Found
Jun 09, 2017 11:27:08 AM hudson.model.Run execute
INFO: RED_Gerrit_Main #80 main build action completed: SUCCESS
Jun 09, 2017 11:27:08 AM com.sonyericsson.hudson.plugins.gerrit.trigger.gerritnotifier.ToGerritRunListener allBuildsCompleted
INFO: All Builds are completed for cause: GerritCause: PatchsetCreated: Change-Id for #146581: Ie3f68ce8a2c07190b22b982c66d0a65f67d2887d PatchSet: 1 silent: false
Jun 09, 2017 11:27:08 AM org.terracotta.jenkins.plugins.postcompleted.PostCompletedRunListener onCompleted
INFO: The url to submit to is not valid, please check your global configuration
Jun 09, 2017 11:27:08 AM com.sonymobile.tools.gerrit.gerritevents.workers.rest.AbstractRestCommandJob run
SEVERE: Gerrit response: Found
```

From user accounts POV, Jenkins account and node accounts are not valid gerrit ones,there is a predefined gerrit account with key pairs used in Gerrit Trigger configuration and Job configuration.

What can be an issue that Gerrit Trigger does not comment back?

Comment: Did you well [configured REST API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger#GerritTrigger-SetupRequirements) ?

Comment: It seems so, REST API usr/pass is provided, checks on Code-Review and Verified. Test Rest Connection is "Success".

Comment: Did you have just one Gerrit server configured? If you have more than one, is Jenkins job using the correct server?